# What is the constructor in this Java file doing?

Tags: java, constructor, metadata, gif

I just stumbled upon this GifSequenceWriter here http://dke-tron.googlecode.com/svn-history/r39/trunk/src/nl/unimaas/games/tron/util/GifSequenceWriter.java . The code of the constructor is this:

```
public GifSequenceWriter(
  ImageOutputStream outputStream,
  int imageType,
  int timeBetweenFramesMS,
  boolean loopContinuously) throws IIOException, IOException {
// my method to create a writer
gifWriter = getWriter(); 
imageWriteParam = gifWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
ImageTypeSpecifier imageTypeSpecifier =
  ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromBufferedImageType(imageType);

imageMetaData =
  gifWriter.getDefaultImageMetadata(imageTypeSpecifier,
  imageWriteParam);

String metaFormatName = imageMetaData.getNativeMetadataFormatName();

IIOMetadataNode root = (IIOMetadataNode)
  imageMetaData.getAsTree(metaFormatName);

IIOMetadataNode graphicsControlExtensionNode = getNode(
  root,
  "GraphicControlExtension");

graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("disposalMethod", "none");
graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("userInputFlag", "FALSE");
graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute(
  "transparentColorFlag",
  "FALSE");
graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute(
  "delayTime",
  Integer.toString(timeBetweenFramesMS / 10));
graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute(
  "transparentColorIndex",
  "0");

IIOMetadataNode commentsNode = getNode(root, "CommentExtensions");
commentsNode.setAttribute("CommentExtension", "Created by MAH");

IIOMetadataNode appEntensionsNode = getNode(
  root,
  "ApplicationExtensions");

IIOMetadataNode child = new IIOMetadataNode("ApplicationExtension");

child.setAttribute("applicationID", "NETSCAPE");
child.setAttribute("authenticationCode", "2.0");

int loop = loopContinuously ? 0 : 1;

child.setUserObject(new byte[]{ 0x1, (byte) (loop & 0xFF), (byte)
  ((loop >> 8) & 0xFF)});
appEntensionsNode.appendChild(child);

imageMetaData.setFromTree(metaFormatName, root);

gifWriter.setOutput(outputStream);

gifWriter.prepareWriteSequence(null);
}
```

Is simply dont understand what this constructor is essentially doing? Just writing some Metadata? can someone explain me this? Why do I need metadata?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/gif_metadata.html

Comment: Every image format would have some meta data, Is this question all about why is it being handled in Constructor?

Comment: @Karthikeyan Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor is apparently setting up the `GifSequenceWriter` so that the initial metadata with the proper content will have been written to the underlying output stream.

Analogous behavior can be seen in [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.java.html), where the constructor writes header information to the underlying stream.